# write data to different lines in a for loop

Tags: python

I have the next code, I would like to print/write the data from the first part of the loop to one line (txt.file) and the data from the second loop (i=0 to len(list)) to the next(i line)

here is the code:

```
transpose=open ('transpose_test.txt','w')
e=open('sorted_ms_dos_test.txt')
for  line in e:
        eid=line[4:10]
        for i,val in enumerate(unic):
            if val==eid and val==unic[0]: 
                transpose.write(line)     
                print(line)
            else:
                if val==eid and val==unic[0+i]:
                    transpose.write(line)
transpose.close()
```

where:
`unic = ['82077 ', '82076 ']` (only in this case, for the real problem `len(unic)` could be more than 20k

the lines from the e looks like:

```
1   82077 6.40
1   82076 7.22
2   82077 18.34
2   82076 16.74
3   82077 6.92
3   82076 7.53
4   82077 10.61
4   82076 12.05
5   82077 10.50
5   82076 10.92
6   82077 127.49
6   82076 106.18
7   82077 11.90
7   82076 13.94
8   82077 13.02
8   82076 14.68
9   82077 16.40
9   82076 15.59
10  82077 10.51
10  82076 11.57
11  82077 66.78
11  82076 64.70
12  82077 10.35
12  82076 11.28
```

am I getting this:

> 1   82077 6.401   82076 7.222   82077 18.342   82076 16.743   82077 6.923   82076 7.534   82077 10.614   82076 12.055   82077 10.505   82076 10.926   82077 127.496   82076 106.187   82077 11.907   82076 13.948   82077 13.028   82076 14.689   82077 16.409   82076 15.5910  82077 10.5110  82076 11.5711  82077 66.7811  82076 64.7012  82077 10.3512  82076 11.28

and I would like to get this:

> 1   **82077** 6.40  2   82077 18.34  3   82077 6.92  4   82077 10.61  5   82077 10.50  6   82077 127.49  7   82077 11.90  8   82077 13.02  9   82077 16.40  10  82077 10.51  11  82077 66.78  12  82077 10.35 # in one line

and

> 1   **82076** 7.22  2   82076 16.74  3   82076 7.53  4   82076 12.05  5   82076 10.92  6   82076 106.18  7   82076 13.94  8   82076 14.68  9   82076 15.59  10  82076 11.57  11  82076 64.70  12  82076 11.28 # in the second line and so on...

Comment: Take a look at `itertools.islice` and `itertools.izip` documentation

Answer (score 0):

First read in all lines, sort them by eid. After that, you can write the output in one loop:

```
from collections import defaultdict
lines_with_eid = defaultdict(list)
with open()'sorted_ms_dos_test.txt') as lines:
    for line in lines:
        lines_with_eid[line[4:10]].append(line.strip())

with open ('transpose_test.txt', 'w') as transpose:
    for val in unic:
        transpose.write(' '.join(lines_with_eid[val]) + '\n')
```

Comment: by **print(lines_with_eid)** I was able to see the desired output, but nothing was written to 'transpose_test.txt